# Power BI M logic has error in conditional if then statement

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have the following column added into my PBI (as an example):

```
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Launch Week", each if 
    [Date] = #date(2021,04,15)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,14)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,16)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,17)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,18)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,19)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,20)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,21)
 then "Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21)"
 else if
    [Date] = #date(2021,04,22) 
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,23)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,24)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,25)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,26)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,27)
    or [Date] = #date(2021,04,28)
 then "Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28)"
else null),
```

What I want to see is something like this:
[image: something like this]

What I'm seeing is actually this:

[image: error on entire column]

It would make sense if it was just null for the entire column for all values that fall out of the date ranges specified, but even the date ranges in range are throwing an error. I'm not sure if there's a M code issue with the logic built in.

Comment: post the error you are getting

Comment: Click on the Error text and show exactly what error message its showing.

Comment: You may want to create a proper date table rather than use this kind of 'switch' logic in your m query.   You would have a list of all likely dates, and in an additional column you would have the appropriate 'week name' that corresponds to that date.  Rather than add this text to the actual fact table, you could access it through a relationship to the date table.  This would be a lot more maintainable as well as opening the door for some proper date intelligence.

Comment: @ashokAnumula and @ mkRabbani there is no error text generated, I've tried finding what the error reads as, but no pop up happens and the query continues on to the next step as if an error didn't happen.

Comment: @ryanB. this is a flash report, so the launch week will change, depending on the report. Some products launch in the middle of the month, some at that beginning, some on a Monday, some on a Friday, so I built out the logic according to a template to make it easier to set when the launch weeks start, when they end, etc.

I have a date table for this, but its not a proper one in conventional sense. It's currently just the launch weeks as a string, and the fact table I mentioned is connected to that "date" table by the launch week. I probably can do this better.

Answer (score 1):

Without clicking on the error to see specifically what the message is, we cannot troubleshoot it for you.

When I generate a reproducible example, this is what it looks like:

```vb
let
    Start = #date(2021, 04, 15),
    End = #date(2021, 04, 28),
    Days = Duration.Days(Duration.From(End - Start)),
    Source =
        List.Dates(
            Start,
            Days,
            #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)
        ),
    ToTable =
        Table.FromList(
            Source,
            Splitter.SplitByNothing(),
            {"Date"},
            null,
            ExtraValues.Error
        ),
    add_LaunchWeek =
        Table.AddColumn(
            ToTable,
            "Launch Week",
            each
                if [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 15) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 14) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 16) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 17) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 18) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 19) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 20) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 21)
                    then "Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21)"
                else if [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 22) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 23) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 24) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 25) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 26) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 27) 
                    or [Date] = #date(2021, 04, 28)
                    then "Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28)"
                else
                    null,
            type text
        )
in
    add_LaunchWeek
```

There are no errors. This is the result:

| Date | Launch Week |
| --- | --- |
| 15/04/2021 | Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21) |
| 16/04/2021 | Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21) |
| 17/04/2021 | Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21) |
| 18/04/2021 | Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21) |
| 19/04/2021 | Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21) |
| 20/04/2021 | Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21) |
| 21/04/2021 | Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21) |
| 22/04/2021 | Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28) |
| 23/04/2021 | Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28) |
| 24/04/2021 | Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28) |
| 25/04/2021 | Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28) |
| 26/04/2021 | Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28) |
| 27/04/2021 | Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28) |

Therefore, I can conclude that there is an error with your input date. Like the `[Date]` column is a text value or something?

However, to streamline your query, you should probably do something like this for the final step  It is a lot more streamlined.

```vb
add_LaunchWeek =
    Table.AddColumn(
        ToTable,
        "Launch Week",
        each
            if [Date] >= #date(2021, 04, 15) 
                and [Date] <= #date(2021, 04, 21)
                then "Week 1 (Apr. 15 - Apr. 21)"
            else if [Date] >= #date(2021, 04, 22) 
                and [Date] <= #date(2021, 04, 28)
                then "Week 2 (Apr. 22 - Apr. 28)"
            else
                null,
        type text
    )
```